# How to check connection of QBluetoothSocket with paired device

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth, qt5, qt5.12

```
if(socket->peerAddress().toString()!=addressToConnect)
```

i did it that way, where

`socket` - object of QBluetoothSocket

`addressToConnect` - QString object with contains address that socket been connected to

but that works only if connected device shuts off, and then turns on again, is there a way to check connection without getting device turning on again, in case it's just lost power, or something of that kind?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to know if the device is still connected?

As per Documentation the socekt class provides the `QBluetoothSocket::state()` and `QBlutoothSocket::error()` functions. 
They provide the `QBluetoothSocket::ConnectedState` and `QBluetoothSocket::RemoteHostClosedError` (since Qt 5.10) types that might be what you are searching for.

You can then combine this with the check of the address you want to connect to.